# "Method 'Expire' in type 'ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient' from assembly

Tags: redis, servicestack

I get the following error when I try to load my webrole locally.

Method 'Expire' in type 'ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Redis, Version=3.9.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

It was working yesterday... Any ideas?

Comment: Is it updated to use the latest versions from NuGet?